Show that if $E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_n)\rightarrow_p 0$ then $X_n\rightarrow_p 0$.
Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-negative integrable random variables.
i. Show that $X_n\rightarrow_p 0$ if and only if $E(\min(X_n,1))\rightarrow 0$.
ii. Show that if $E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_n)\rightarrow_p 0$ then $X_n\rightarrow_p 0$ and converse is not true.
Proof of i.
We know that
\begin{align*}
\lim_n E[\min(X_n,1)]&=\lim_n \int^1_0P(X_n\geq x)dx \\
&= \int^1_0\lim_nP(X_n\geq x)dx\\
&=0
\end{align*}
I am struggling with ii.). I think I should use the result of i.) to prove ii.)
Proof of ii.  (Using Sangchul Lee's hint)
Using result of part i.
$\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid\mathcal{F_n}]\rightarrow_p 0 \iff \mathbb{E}\Big(\min\{\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid\mathcal{F_n}],1\}\Big)\rightarrow 0$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_n,1\}]
=
\mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_n,1\}\mid\mathcal{F_n}]\Big)
\leq
\mathbb{E}\Big(\min\{\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid\mathcal{F_n}],1\}\Big)\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
So $\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_n,1\}]\rightarrow 0$, which implies $X_n\rightarrow_p 0$ by another application of (i.).

What is $ \mu$?

Here is a hint:
If $X$ is non-negative and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field, then by the concavity of the function $x\mapsto\min\{1,x\}$ and the conditional Jensen's inequality,
$$\mathbb{E}[\min\{X,1\}\mid\mathcal{F}]\leq\min\{\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}],1\}$$
holds $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely. Now can you conclude from part (i)?

Thank you! Let me give this a try.
